# Approval Process: Only Commit Users Selection on Approval

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, approval-process

Here is the use case I am having trouble with:

A user needs to transfer a case to another office, office is a picklist. When the Picklist Value is updated, seek approval from a manager. If approved, respect the change that the user made and send approval email, if denied do not respect the change.

The key here is that I do not want to commit a users change until AFTER approval is provided. On approval actions, it looks like I can only update the Picklist Value to a specific value.

I am currently launching the approval process from a Screen Flow where the user selects a new office location. My plan was to have that input update a 'Requested Office' Picklist field. Upon approval, the process would update the Picklist Value of Office to the value in 'Requested Office' but again, I can only update the Picklist Value to a specific value.

​​​​​​​Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Received an answer from another forum:

1) Have a field to track approval status. Let us say field Name is "Approval Status"
2) Have another field called "New Office". Let the user fill in this field with the new office and then submit the record for approval
3) Once the approver approves the record, as a final approval action, populate the field "Approval Status" as Approved
4) Then configure a process builder on the same object that triggers when "Approval Status" is updated to Approved. Immediate action for this process would be to populate value from "New Office" field to "Office" field.

Comment: that seems like a good approach.  if you allow user to update requested office directly, that will be saved immediately - before approval is complete.  you should be able to dynamically set choice label and value,which would allow you to use your initial approach, but i dont think that would meet your requirements - as the update would be saved immediately, not after approval.